# Path finding Algorithm - multiple tasks

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, floyd-warshall

I have a project for school where I have to find the shortest route available between two Nodes using Floyd Warshall and Dijkstra Algorithms. All well and good however, further to this I have to provide an amendment to both algorithms so that the optimal route for multiple tasks is computed.

The scenario is based on a public transport pickup/dropoff. For example: you would have a person wanting to go from C to B, and another from D to B, and maybe another from C to F.

The concept is to always start from node A, and compute the optimal route for catering all requests.

Anyone with an idea of the right direction to approach this?

Comment: It sounds like the traveling salesman problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: The problem looks computationally hard. How many nodes do you have? How many pickup/dropoff requests do you have?

Comment: Hi Niklas, number of nodes is selected at runtime and they are generated. EACH node is connected to every other node with a 2-way "road" however the distance is (original distance + or - 50%) to counter the direct route always being the best choice.

Also, any number of requests. But all requests will have a pickup and dropoff location.

Comment: Hello Khaelid, it looks a lot close to being the solution. However, from what I picked up the TSP does not consider having to pick up a passenger from >A< before going to where he is to be dropped off.

Comment: Just so you know, I have altered Dijkstra to start from a Point (A) and find the closest objective (objectives are stored in a collection as complete/incomplete). Upon reaching this objective, Dijkstra loops again, starting from this new point, to the next closest objective.